# How do i update object using php-sdk? (The parameter object is required)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

```
$response = $facebook->api(
  'me/objects/namespace:result',
  'POST',
  array(
    'app_id' => app_id,
    'type' => "namespace:result",
    'url' => "http://samples.ogp.me/370740823026684",
    'title' => "Sample Result",
    'image' => "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png",
    'description' => ""
  )
);
```

I get the following error.

```
The parameter object is required
```

I don't know where to add the parameter object.

Comment: What is `me/objects` supposed to be? Custom actions are created by posting to `/{user-id}/{namespace}:{action-type-name}`. And what is your object type called? You have to use the `type` parameter as well, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/

Comment: object name is result. I want to update the object with php. i am not posting action. I heard the array must be json encoded. But i don't know where to specify the object parameter.

Comment: @CBroe I found this. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/17153617/facebook-javascript-sdk-open-graph-error-adding-custom-objects-for-custom-stori --> I still don't know how to use the object parameter in php.

Comment: You can _see_ in the answer there how it's used ...

Comment: but how do i do that in php? object: json_encode($array).. how do i use that object in php?

Comment: i tried this.. $object = "object: ".json_encode($params_graph); where params_graph is the array. $facebook->api("/me/objects/namespace:result","POST",$object); giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue for the past couple of days, in the end I stopped trying to use the Facebook PHP SDK to send the request and resorted to using just sending a HTTP Request.

I am creating an object rather than updating one, but the implementation shouldn't differ much from your needs. I was getting the same error (The parameter object is required) and the below implementation resolved that issue.

I used the vinelab HTTP client composer package and built a request like this:

```
$request = [
        'url' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/objects/namespace:object',
        'params' => [
            'access_token' => $fbAccessToken,
            'method' => 'POST',
            'object' => json_encode([
                'fb:app_id'         => 1234567890,
                'og:url'            => 'http://samples.ogp.me/1234567890',
                'og:title'          => 'Sample Object',
                'og:image'          => 'https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png',
                'og:description'    => 'Sample Object'
            ])
        ]
    ];

// I'm using Laravel so this bit might look different for you (check the vine lab docs if you use that specific HTTP client)
$response = HttpClient::post($request);

// raw content
$response->content();

// json
$response->json();
```

As I said, I used the vinelab HTTP package in my implementation, you should be able to use any similar package or directly use curl in PHP instead.